# which reporter setup?

Tags: microphone, portable-recorder, recorder

looking to find a great sounding (low noise, warm vocal tone) way to record in reporter-style, so on the road but also indoors with small recorder plus mic.

very open question, but please go ahead! :)

Answer (score 1):

You cant go wrong with the H4.

http://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/H4N/

This is a great stereo mic, as well as having the ability to use 2 more mics.

You could use some great large diaphragm condensers for your warm vocal tone, and hand held it reporter style, as I see many people using the H2 reporter style over the TV right now. You could even use a shotgun on a boom if you needed! Talk about a versatile portable recorder for only 300 bucks!

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I do this all the time with an Zoom H4 (the model previous to H4n) and a Rode M3. Gives nice tone, looks professional and you can put a flag on it. I also use a Sennheiser EW100G3 kit with the plugin transmitter to give the reporter even more freedom if you are using a simple camera setup (with a shotgun on the camera).